# Show if a form hidden field based on the value of the object, rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, coffeescript

I'm a learning programmer that only know Ruby on Rails and I know nothing of Javascript. I have a form in ruby on rails that creates a object Unit. The model Unit belong to Category that in turn belongs to Product.So in the form you need to select a product for the unit and then a category. The problem I had was you could select any Category but each product only have some categories. So I modified js code that I found on the internet so that when you selected Product, the select Category appeared and showed only the categories available for that product.

```
jQuery ->
  $('#unit_category_id').parent().hide()
  categories = $('#unit_category_id').html()
  $('#unit_product_id').change ->
    product = $('#unit_product_id :selected').text()
    options = $(categories).filter("optgroup[label='#{product}']").html()
    if options
      $('#unit_category_id').html(options)
      $('#unit_category_id').parent().show()
    else
      $('#unit_category_id').empty()
      $('#unit_category_id').parent().hide()
```

The problem I have now is that when I edit the unit, the unit's product is selected correctly but the category is hidden. Only when I reselect the product the category field appears. Can someone help me modify this JS code so that in the edit the category field appears based on the product selected based on the units product? Thanks a lot! I added some photos for better describing my problem.

Photo 1: Edit of a Unit with product: bolsa and category: weekend bag
[image: Edit of a Unit, product: Bolsa, category: Weekend Bag wit]

Photo 2: The problem is that when I select category to edit it shows all categories and not just the product categories.
[image]

Photo 3: When I reselect the product the categories are shown correctly

[image]

I want to fix the code so the categories are show correctly from the beginning.

Based on the Answer I fixed my problem like this:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#unit_category_id').parent().show()
  categories = $('#unit_category_id').html()
  product = $('#unit_product_id :selected').text()
  options = $(categories).filter("optgroup[label='#{product}']").html()
  if options
    $('#unit_category_id').html(options)
    $('#unit_category_id').parent().show()
  else
    $('#unit_category_id').empty()
    $('#unit_category_id').parent().hide()
    
  $('#unit_product_id').change ->
    product = $('#unit_product_id :selected').text()
    options = $(categories).filter("optgroup[label='#{product}']").html()
    if options
      $('#unit_category_id').html(options)
      $('#unit_category_id').parent().show()
    else
      $('#unit_category_id').empty()
      $('#unit_category_id').parent().hide()
```

Comment: For what it's worth, that is CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `$('#unit_category_id').parent().show()` in the change callback, before assigning options.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm sorry but I made a mistake and what I'm describing is with the change you suggested. I have edited my question and I'm gonna add some pics

Comment: Oh I see. So the default selected value for product is Bolsa? The problem is the change event, which makes the other category groups disappear is not fired if you don't change the default selected value to something else. You need to copy the chunck of code in the change callback and add the copy outside of the callback, so that the categories are set properly at first time. Afterwards I would also suggest to refactor the code a bit

Comment: product = $('#unit_product_id :selected').text()
    options = $(categories).filter("optgroup[label='#{product}']").html()
    if options
      $('#unit_category_id').html(options)
      $('#unit_category_id').parent().show()
    else
      $('#unit_category_id').empty()
      $('#unit_category_id').parent().hide()

Comment: Something like this?

Comment: That sure fixed the issue. Thanks!